# Scheduled Android Notification push on startup

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am developing the schedule notification for Android. It is successfully get notification at scheduled time but also get notification at the time when the application startup which I do not want. Here are my codes.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    prefs= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    show = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    View btn_failure = findViewById(R.id.btn_failure_id);
    btn_failure.setOnClickListener(this);
    View btn_unhappy = findViewById(R.id.btn_unhappy_id);
    btn_unhappy.setOnClickListener(this);
    View btn_chicken_soup = findViewById(R.id.btn_soup_id);
    btn_chicken_soup.setOnClickListener(this);
    View btn_no_motivation = findViewById(R.id.btn_no_id);
    btn_no_motivation.setOnClickListener(this);

//  createScheduledNotification(9,0);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    time = prefs.getString("noti", "9:00");
    String[] pieces=time.split(":");
    hour = Integer.parseInt(pieces[0]);
    minute = Integer.parseInt(pieces[1]);
    boolean onOff = prefs.getBoolean("noti_10",true);
    createScheduleNotification(hour,minute,onOff);
}

public void createScheduleNotification(int hour, int minute, boolean onOff){
    if(onOff){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, getPendingIntent(this));
    }else{
        AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        mgr.cancel(getPendingIntent(this));
    }
}

private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context ctxt) {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(ctxt, TimeAlarm.class);
    intent1.putStringArrayListExtra("quotes",quote_chicken_soup);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return pendingIntent;
}


public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private String daily_quote = "testing";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent paramIntent) {

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context,DisplayActivity.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("quote",paramIntent.getStringArrayListExtra("quotes"));
        daily_quote = paramIntent.getStringArrayListExtra("quotes").get(0);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent, 0);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setTicker("Daily Quote");
        builder.setContentTitle("Daily Quote");
        builder.setContentText(daily_quote);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            builder.setSubText("Be Happy! Have a nice day!");   //API level 16
        }

        Notification myNotication = builder.getNotification();
        manager.notify(11, myNotication);
    }

}
```

Where is the problem that cause the notification being push when app startup?

Comment: The issue is not with your notification code. Check the trigger of broadcast receiver, which is triggering the notification code.

Comment: @Nicks I have uploaded my codes for AlarmManager which use to trigger the broadcast receiver. Can u help me to look through it? Thanks

Comment: From where is this createschedulenotification() called?  That piece of code may help.

Comment: @Nicks Initially I called in onCreate then I try in onResume but both give me the same results. I have edited my code. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Can you try using ELAPSED_REALtIME_WAKEUP instead of RTC_WAKEUP and SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()

Comment: Is it like this `am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,getPendingIntent(this));` ?

Answer (score 1):

There seems nothing wrong in your code.
Issue with notification being pushed up at startup is surely because of AlarmManager code.

From your code snippet, I hard coded the setting of time as below, and it runs as expected . First time it triggers in one minute after the system clock and then every 2 minutes there after.

```
      // first time set to-- trigger after one minute from now
long firstTimeTriggerAt = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000 * 60 * 1;
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
       //Repeat the alaram every two minutes
        long interval =  1000 * 60 * 2;
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,firstTimeTriggerAt, interval, getPendingIntent(this));
```

So you need to check the constant values for time, which you are setting in Shared preference. 
 Just FYI , the code runs well with RTC_WAKEUP constant also.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to fire the notification daily at the time set in preference. In this case, how can i check the constant value? I dun really understand that. And what is FYI?

Comment: @SamTew, FYI- For your information. Why dont you first try hardcoading the time and testing. I have run the app code and  it works fine, notification is not getting pushed at app startup, so the issue is with the time you are setting

Comment: Oic~Ok, i will try it out later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in onResume() change

```
boolean onOff = prefs.getBoolean("noti_10",true);
```

to

```
boolean onOff = prefs.getBoolean("noti_10",false);
```